# How do I convert Rust `Args` into the argc and argv C equivalents?

Tags: c, rust

I am using a C API (in particular `MPI_Init`) that needs `int argc, char **argv`. I am trying to generate an equivalent `argc, argv` with the following code:

```
let argc = std::env::args().len() as c_int;
let c_strs: ~[CString] = std::env:args().map(|s: & &str| s.to_c_str());
let mut argv: ~[*c_char] = c_strs.map(|c: &CString| c.with_ref(|ptr| ptr));
if null_terminate {
    argv.push(std::ptr::null());
}
```

By adapting [this discussion on Github](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/9564).

It fails with:

```
error: expected type, found `~`
src/lib.rs:37   let c_strs: ~[CString] = std::env::args().map(|s: & &str| s.to_c_str());
                            ^
```

I got rid of the `~` and then it could not find `to_c_str()` and was unsure what to replace `to_c_str` with, `to_raw()` (for instance) failed.

Does anyone know of a way to convert `Args` to a more C friendly format?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://codeseekah.com/2015/01/25/rusts-osargs-to-cs-argv/

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I get an unresolved import `std::os::args_as_bytes`. I tried using a nightly and beta build. Neither of them could find it.

Comment: Just to be clear: `~` was removed from the language quite some time ago.  It turned (variously) into `Box`, `Vec`, and `String`, depending on context.  If you see it in example code, it's out of date and probably not very useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My answer works with the current stable Rust (1.5) and probably with beta and nightly.

The following Rust code calls the `foo(argc, argv)` function implemented in C. The signature of `foo` is very similar to a `main` function.

```rs
extern crate libc;

use libc::c_char;
use libc::c_int;

use std::ffi::CString;

#[link(name="foo")]
extern "C" {
    fn foo(argc: c_int, argv: *const *const c_char);
}

fn main() {
    // create a vector of zero terminated strings
    let args = std::env::args().map(|arg| CString::new(arg).unwrap() ).collect::<Vec<CString>>();
    // convert the strings to raw pointers
    let c_args = args.iter().map(|arg| arg.as_ptr()).collect::<Vec<*const c_char>>();
    unsafe {
        // pass the pointer of the vector's internal buffer to a C function
        foo(c_args.len() as c_int, c_args.as_ptr());
    };
}
```

Note, that the C side only **borrows** the pointers to the strings. If you want to store them, use `strdup()` on them.

I also used `unwrap()` on `CString` instances. If your string contains 0 bytes, it will  return an error, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.new.

Proof:

I put this code into a cargo project, and added `libc` as a dependency. 
The `foo()` function looks like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
}
```

I compiled this code with:

```sh
gcc foo.c -o libfoo.so -shared -fPIC
```

Then copied `libfoo.so` under `target/debug/deps` (just to be in the library search path). Then I run my cargo project:

```sh
$ cargo run the quick brown fox
   Compiling args v0.1.0 (file:///home/tibi/Codes/Rust/argv/args)
     Running `target/debug/args the quick brown fox`
argv[0]: target/debug/args
argv[1]: the
argv[2]: quick
argv[3]: brown
argv[4]: fox
```

Comment: You should push `ptr::null()` to the end of `c_args` (and then subtract 1 from `.len()`) as C code may (validly) rely on a NULL sentinel at the end of argv.